# Insert Image using XSL or XML

Tags: xml, xslt

My POS uses an XSL File as a template for my Receipts, I would like to insert an image at the top of my receipts such as a logo. I've tried adding an Image but my an image doesn't Print/is displayed, What do I need to do?

Below is the code I have tried

Do I have to add any code to the XML file?

```
      <img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:value-of select="http://tpg-consultants.co.uk/Recipet/TPG-CON.png"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
      </img>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
      <xsl:value-of select="http://tpg-consultants.co.uk/Recipet/TPG-CON.png"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
```

use:

```
<xsl:attribute name="src">http://tpg-consultants.co.uk/Recipet/TPG-CON.png</xsl:attribute>
```

Or just replace the entire `img` element with:

```
<img src="http://tpg-consultants.co.uk/Recipet/TPG-CON.png"/>
```

---

What you have now is trying to get the value from a node, using an invalid XPath expression.

Comment: This is the error i now recieve using the above code:                                             System Error Cannot create an attribute node (src) whose parent is a document node. Most recent element start tag was output at line -1 of module *unknown*

Comment: Did you not keep the parent `img` element?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you without seeing the context. See: [mcve].